# Application unfortunately has been stopped while implementing simple fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My MainActivity contents is :

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    my_frag myFrag = new my_frag();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,myFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

fragment class is :

```
public class my_frag extends Fragment {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_frag, container, false);
            }
```

Main xml is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <fragment
        android:layout_width="2000dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:name="com.example.gcoeara.mywork.my_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_frag" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Namespace is as follows :

```
activity name : MainActivity.java
main xml : activity_main.xml
fragment name : my_frag.java
fragment class : fragment_my_frag.xml
```

system : windows 7
framework : android studio

log cat is :

```
Process: com.example.gcoeara.mywork, PID: 22847
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gcoeara.mywork/com.example.gcoeara.mywork.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
                at com.example.gcoeara.mywork.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.gcoeara.mywork.my_fragment did not create a view.
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2145)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
                at com.example.gcoeara.mywork.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: Your attribute of fragment in Main_activity.xml android:name="com.example.gcoeara.mywork.my_fragment" and the namespace mentioned for fragment by you fragment name : my_frag.java are different. Please make it same and check whether you are still getting error

Comment: ok. i did suggested change but still getting same error :-(

Comment: Also do you need the width of fragment to be 2000dp ?Please check that also and if you are still getting error then Please update the question with the new logcat report

Comment: yeah.. i got error...i accidently assign login button to getFragment method

Comment: so it was different error

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:name="com.example.gcoeara.mywork.my_fragment"
```

in your fragment to

```
android:name="com.example.gcoeara.mywork.my_frag"
```

Hope you have the  package path for my_frag as
com.example.gcoeara.mywork.my_frag.